# What's a good, cheap printer that connects to a MacBook?

Tags: printer, apple

I have a mid-2014 Retina 15-inch MacBook Pro. I'm looking to buy a good cheap printer to connect to this MacBook, preferably by USB. What printers would you recommend?

I'm hoping to buy a printer that's less than $100. If I can get a good one for less than $50 that would be great.

Comment: @K7AAY Without getting too philosophical, I'd say, something that has good reviews, is reliable, and looks nice.

Answer (score 1):

Brother printers [support MacOS X](https://support.brother.com/g/b/faqend.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=hl5450dn_all&faqid=faq00000365_002), and connect by USB. I'd suggest the B&W [Brother LH-L2320D](https://www.staples.com/Brother-HL-L2320D-Monochrome-Laser-Printer/product_1074269) which offers duplexing for $80 FOB Destination (US).  Toner refills are also relatively inexpensive.

Had mine (two models up, an all-in-one B&W w/ WiFi I got on sale for $90) over a year with absolutely no problem in printing from MacOS X, Windows 10, and various Linux distros. Bought based on a very positive review at https://boingboing.net - other reviews listed at https://google.com/search?q=brother+printer+review